# Casting of dates does not honor locale settings in postgresql 15

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, locale, postgresql-15

I'm trying to understand all the bits and bobs of postgresql 15 and locale settings. I am trying to set all the various settings that control the locale, but I'm still getting some unexpected results.

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE lctest TEMPLATE='template0' LC_COLLATE='nb_NO.UTF-8' LOCALE='nb_NO.UTF-8';
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \c lctest
You are now connected to database "lctest" as user "postgres".
lctest=# show LC_TIME;
   lc_time    
-------------
 nb_NO.UTF-8
(1 row)

lctest=# select DATE('07/08/2009');
    date
------------
 2009-07-08
(1 row)

lctest=# select to_char(DATE('07/08/2009'), 'DD/TMMonth/YYYY');
    to_char
--------------
 08/Juli/2009
(1 row)
```

And this is where I think the result is unexpected. I am casting a date from a string, and postgres is interpreting the date as `MM/DD/YYYY`. This is not in line with the expected result given my locale settings. I have also set all the other available `LC_*` values to `nb_NO.UTF-8`, and as expected I get the same result, because I don't believe the other values should affect this.

Are there more settings that can affect how date strings are parsed in postgres 15?

I could of course specify the date format as `DD/MM/YYYY`, but that breaks the flexibility in the locale settings. If I have to specify all format details, what's the point of locale, right?

Comment: I have discovered now that there's another setting called `DateStyle`, which specifically sets whether these dates should be interpreted as `DMY` or `MDY`. But I have yet to figure out how to make this setting dependent on any locale settings. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE

Comment: You could set the DateStyle in your session to 'ISO, DMY' or 'ISO, MDY' based on your locale preferences. `SET DateStyle = 'ISO, DMY';`

Answer (score 0):

`lc_time` does not influence how strings are interpreted as dates. It is used in `to_char()` (format timestamps as string) with special format directives like `TMMonth`.

To influence how strings are interpreted as dates, you have to configure `datestyle`. For example:

```
SET datestyle = 'GERMAN, DMY';

select DATE('07/08/2009');

    date    
════════════
 07.08.2009
(1 row)
```